# Proving on Linear approximation

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

We know that $f(a+Δx) \approx f(a) + f'(a)Δx$.

If $e(Δx) = f(a + Δx) - f(a) - f'(a)Δx$, how can we prove that:
$$\lim_{Δx\to 0}e(Δx) = 0, \lim_{Δx\to0}\frac{e(Δx)}{Δx} = 0 ?$$

If we write $f'(x)$ as $\frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h}$ when ${h\to0}$ can we say $f'(x)Δx = f(a + Δx) - f(a)?$ I mean $h$ and $x$ both approach $0$ but how can we say $\frac{Δx} {h} = 1?$ or $f(a + h) = f(a + Δx)?$

Can we say when ${Δx\to0}$, $e(Δx)$ not only approaches $0$ but it approaches $0$ faster than $Δx$, by proving these? why?

Comment: In general, it's the definition of $f'(a)$ or how have you defined it?

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align}f'(a)&=\lim_{\Delta x\to0}\frac{f(a+\Delta x)-f(a)}{\Delta x}\\\lim_{\Delta x\to0}\frac{e(\Delta x)}{\Delta x}&=\lim_{\Delta x\to0}\frac{f(a+\Delta x)-f(a)-f'(a)\Delta x}{\Delta x}\\&=\lim_{\Delta x\to0}\frac{f(a+\Delta x)-f(a)}{\Delta x}-\lim_{\Delta x\to0}\frac{f'(a)\Delta x}{\Delta x}\\&=f'(a)-f'(a)\\&=0\end{align}$$